# JQuery load not replacing content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a weather bar set up to load a php file called data.php every 10 seconds using setInterval and .load. I can see in Firebug that the setInterval is working and it seems like the load is too but when it runs it does not get the most current version of the data.php file.

index.php

```
<div id="weather"></div>

<script>
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
        $('#weather').load('assets/fb_weather/data.php');
    }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

data.php

```
<div id="fb_weather_wrapper">
    <p id="fb_weather_today">Current</p>
    <div id="fb_weather_top">
        <div class="one-half">Mt. Carmel, IL</div>
        <div class="one-half"><?=$today_date?></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fb_weather_icons fb_weather_icons_<?=$cond->icon?>"></div>
    <p id="fb_weather_temp"><? echo round($cond->temp_f); ?>&deg;</p>
    <p class="fb_weather_cond"><?=$cond->weather?></p>

    <div id="fb_weather_forecast">
        <ul>
            <? foreach($forecast->forecast->simpleforecast->forecastdays->forecastday as $day)
            { ?>
            <li class="fb_weather_day">
                <div class="fb_weather_icons_small fb_weather_icons_small_<?=$day->icon?>"></div>
                <p class="fb_weather_forecast_temp"><?=$day->high->fahrenheit?>&deg;<br />
                <p><?=$day->date->weekday_short?></p>
                <em class="clear"></em>
            </li>
            <? } ?>
                <em class="clear"></em>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you might be a victim of the dreaded cache. Have you tried adding say a timestamp to your URL you're calling? `$('#weather').load('assets/fb_weather/data.php?timestamp=<timestamphere>');`

Comment: Also, beware, if something goes bad on the server this is just going to keep running every 10 seconds regardless of if the previous request was successful or not, a quick solution is use a `setTimeout` and re-initiate the function in the callback, nice and recursive.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove your .load() method and make a ajax request:

like

```
$.post('assets/fb_weather/data.php','datastring/dataArray',function(response){
$('#weather').load('assets/fb_weather/data.php');
});
```

data string or array is the value which you want to send to page and you can get this values to your php page

like :

```
print_r($_POST);
```